# Error installing nokogiri: invalid gem: package is corrupt

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to parse a website by using  jekyll on my Debian x64 and I get a problem with this following gem **nokogiri** , in particular I've been required on install the version 1.8.5 , but as it was not working I attempted downloading the last version `nokogiri (1.11.0.rc2)` Manualy from the web and now I'm stuck with this error.

```
bundle exec jekyll serve

Could not find nokogiri-1.8.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

bundle install

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/cache/nokogiri-1.8.5.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.5), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.5' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have it's dependancy library libxml2 try running below code.

```
brew install libxml2
```

if not worked add nokogiri gem using below command

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
 [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
 [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]
```

Comment: thanks, It seems I cannot find any `/path/to/xslt-config]` nor I cant fin that package as `brew install xslt-config` , shall I install nokogiri only with xml12-config ?

Comment: install nokogiri using `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-config=/opt/local/bin/xml2-config --with-xslt-config=/opt/local/bin/xslt-config`